# Git plug-in for Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, git

Is there a plug-in for the Finder which lets me see and do all my git-related stuff?

There are many different apps or the terminal which change the prompt to show that files are “dirty” in terms of not being checked in or showing which branch of the code you are browsing.

I’m wondering if there are any Finder integration or visual indicators that will show if:

- the current directory is under code control
- the current directory has un-committed changes
- is under code control at all

Are there graphical tools that are paid or free that integrate git status with Finder windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SnailGit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snailgit-free-git-client-finder/id1099475282) is close (but not free) alternative to TortoiseGit that works for mac. It does displays badges directly in Finder. And it has right-click git menu for operations on repositories.

Free version is limited to one folder.

Comment: Looks like the closest thing to what I want at the moment, although there are issues with the icon overlay conflicting with Dropbox (I think this is an Apple limitation of only allowing one icon overlay per file/folder)

Comment: Has there been anything new since this was posted in 2016? It's 2019...

Answer (score 4):

Other options, with recent updates, are:

- [GitFinder](https://gitfinder.com)
- [Stat](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stat/id931063335?mt=12)

Comment: GitFinder has a trial version. It did not work for me. The GitFinderSync processes were using a lot of CPU, but no overlay-icons in Finder.
Can anybody confirm that "Stat" is working?

Comment: @jbandi, maybe you can find the reason in one of the FAQ answers: [GitFinder is running, but I don't see icon badges nor git menu commands?](https://gitfinder.com/support)

Comment: Here in 2023, Stat has disappeared from the App Store

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that there is no git plugin for the native Finder app.

The Finder alternative [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) claims to offer GIT and SVN integration, but it costs $39.95. Maybe try the 30 trial to see if it fits your needs?