# How to show git files in Finder?

Tags: finder, git, folder-action

This may be too close to a duplicate for [Git plug-in for Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85440/git-plug-in-for-finder), but I'm after a tool that will merely show me whether there is a repo in the current directory, and the state of the files within.

- I don't want to view all invisible files
- I want to continue using Finder (I like PathFinder, but not always)
- I don't need to run git commands on the files, just see their state

I'm thinking of an interface like Dropbox (see image), or TortoiseSVN for windows... any suggestions or workarounds?

[image: Dropbox's synced indicators in Finder]

Maybe its possible to create a folder automation? (never done such a thing! if it sounds plausible, I'll read up on it)

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Dropbox uses https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject to inject code into the Finder process to change the overlay. This is TRICKY BUSINESS.  Finder in 10.6 can be hacked with a [SIMBL](https://code.google.com/p/simbl/wiki/Tutorial) plugin , you just have to use the swizzling method to reimplement the drawWithFrame method in the Finder.

Comment: heh.. 'must be this tall to ride'.. I don't need to stoop to pass under that bar :) tx for the link!

Answer (score 1):

An update, as there's been movement on this question...

There is a question on SO: [How can i add icon overlay in finder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991131/how-can-i-add-icon-overlay-in-finder) where a comments include Apples update of  points to the [TortoiseSVN Subversion client](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse) 
and a search turned up the following 2yo git repo with some demo code for 10.7: [Finder-Icon-Overlay](https://github.com/lesnie/Finder-Icon-Overlay).

If I get around to messing around with an implementation, I'll update this answer.

Comment: check out [Snail Git](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snailgit-free-git-client-finder/id1099475282)